# getInputStream() very slow on device, but not on emulator

Tags: java, android, https, inputstream

(I believe this question has been asked several times, but often without an accepted answer or with very old or ineffective solutions.)

My app should connect to a server and display read data.  This works fine on the emulator, but as soon as I try it on any real device, `getInputStream()` takes extremely long (15 to 20 seconds instead of 1 to 2 seconds). Interestingly, I have noticed slightly quicker responses when I set `setConnectTimeout()` to a shorter time, but this could lead to more errors.  What am I missing?

What I tried:

```
connection.setUseCaches(false);  
using HttpUrlConnectio instead of HttpsUrlConnection  
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");  
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "1000");
```

Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to Manifest
I did see "No Network Security Config specified, using platform default", but fixing that did not seem to help.

The inner class HttpGetRequest was found in an example and adopted to suit my needs:

```
public class HttpGetRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000; //shorter time works faster!

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        clipEditText.setText("loading...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params){

        String result="";
        String inputLine;

        //create connection
        URL myUrl = null;
        try {
            myUrl = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

         // get the string from the input stream
        InputStreamReader streamReader = null;
        try {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Reading...");
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }

            //clean up when done
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        clipContent = result;

            //show us the data
            clipEditText.setText(clipContent);
     }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it is "getInputStream", not reading process itself?

Comment: Yes, in the original code I have a log before and after getInputStream, so I am certain.  I have edited them out for readability.

Comment: when I set connection.setConnectTimeout(200) it works really fast, so I think it's getting stuck while connecting...

Comment: That vaguely rings a bell. I remember a debugging session of a similar problem. It was the implementation code doing two connect attempts, the first trying to connect to a proxy or such alike, I can’t remember. The key point was that the actual connection was only done when the first attempt failed, so lowering the timeout made the first fail faster.

Comment: The unexplained behaviour went away by itself, that points towards a server issue.
But, before it changed I even tried connecting from PC and Android using POSTMAN and even this had a much slower connection from the android than pc.  The problem is not in the code, but something inside the platform.